# AmazonServiceRequestDelegate function didFailWithServiceException giving me "Request timed out" error

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, delegates

I am using AWSS3 to upload my media to amazon.
This is how I am doing:

```
Bool uploaded = NO;
dispatch_async("my.queue.whatever", ^{

   NSData *mediaData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mediaImage);//mediaImage of type uiimage
   NSString *pictureName = @"randomstring";

   AmazonCredentials *amazonCredentials = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"myAccessKey" withSecretKey:@"mySecretKey" withSecurityToken:@"mySessionToken"];
    AmazonS3Client *s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentials:amazonCredentials];


    S3PutObjectRequest *s3Request = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:pictureName inBucket:@"myPictureBucket"];
    s3Request.delegate = self;
    //s3Request.contentType = CONTENT_TYPE;
    s3Request.cannedACL = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
    s3Request.data = mediaData;
    [s3Client putObject:s3Request];

    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate   distantFuture]];
    } while (!uploaded);
);
```

and these are my delegate functions:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
    uploaded = YES;
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    uploaded = YES;
}
- (void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithServiceException:(NSException *)exception{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithServiceException %@",[exception description]);
    uploaded = YES;
}
- (void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didSendData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(long long)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{}
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{}
```

and when the function didFailWithServiceException is called, it gives me the error: "Request timed out". I can't find anything in google. Need your help!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the default timeout:

```
s3Client.timeout = desiredtimeout;
```

I'm experimenting some problems with the upload operation, it starts to upload but after a couple of seconds the delegate is not called again.

```
request: didSendData: totalBytesWritten: totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
```

I don't know if there is some bug in the framework or in the Amazon servers, or it is just some bug in my code.